# How does return false work inside validate plugin submitHandler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I was just going through the validator plgin examples and found a snippet of code online:

```
$('#testimonials-form').validate({
    rules: {
        "t-title": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 5
        },
        "t-text": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 15
        },
        "person-name": {
            required: true,
            minlength: 4
        },
        "photo": {
            required: true,
            accept: 'image/*'
        }
    },
    messages: {
        "t-title": {
            required: "A title is needed",
            minlength: "minimum 4 characters"
        },
        "t-text": {
            required: "A testimonial is needed",
            minlength: "minimum 15 characters"
        },
        "person-name": {
            required: "A name is needed",
            minlength: "minimum 4 characters"
        },
        "photo": {
            required: "An image for the testimonial giver is needed",
            accept: "Only image file type is accpeted , please check that the file you tried to upload was an image"
        }
    },

    submitHandler: function (form) {

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('photo', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
        formData.append('t-title', $('input[name=t-title]').val());
        formData.append('t-text', $('textarea[name=t-text]').val());
        formData.append('person-name', $('input[name=person-name]').val());


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
            url: 'inc/database.php', // the url where we want to POST
            data: formData,
            // THIS MUST BE DONE FOR FILE UPLOADING
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            // ... Other options like success and etc
        });

        return false;

    }
});
```

Now how come the `return false` works here , in spite of not being attached to a submit button ? I used the above code and it worked perfectly fine , i was just curious to know how the above code works and how especially the `return false` works ?

**EDIT** :: i know how `return false` works , i am asking how come it work's here when they are not attached to the submit button.

Thank you.

Comment: its attached to a form. you can hook into a form's submit event directly without dealing with the submit button. a form doesn't even necessarily need a submit button at all

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The submit handler is called when a submit event on the form is registered. It doesn't have to be tied to a button, just the event.

Comment: only within an event handler of course. Is submitHandler being attached as the callback to an event? (would have to go to validator source)

Comment: @KevinB right i was about to include a link to an SO answer that mentions this.  I've also edited the wording in my answer better.  Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @spaniol6 dude i know what preventDefault and return false do , i am asking how come they work here when they are not attached to the submit button.

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik the submit handler is called when a submit event on the form is registered.  It doesn't have to be tied to a button, just the event.

Comment: correct ur ans than ! thats all i wanted to knw .. nothing more . TY @spaniol6